# PageSpeed reports that Google Analyics is "unused Javascript" when installed by GTM

Tags: seo, page-speed

I'm setting up a new Drupal 9 site.

I have added Google Analytics via Google Tag Manager.

I'm using Universal Analytics and these are my tags:

- Track link clicks
- Track page views
- Track scroll depth

When I run page speed on my site, the only identified "Opportunity" is to **Removed unused Javascript**, which is Tag Manager + Analytics:

```
Remove unused JavaScript

Estimated savings: 0.15 s

Remove unused JavaScript to reduce bytes consumed by network activity. Learn more.
URL

/gtm.js?id=GTM-W8NJ62V(www.googletagmanager.com)
29.2 KB -> 13.5 KB

/analytics.js(www.google-analytics.com)
18.7 KB -> 5.3 KB
```

How do I improve this? Is there a way to set up Google Tag Manager/Analytics to deliver a more compressed version?

Comment: Same issue here!

Comment: Found some thoughts here https://support.google.com/tagmanager/thread/14200490?hl=en

Though, nevermind - most google products itself are very slow so we need some lightweight replacement for GA definitly

Answer (score 1):

Google Tag Manager makes easy and quick to set up Google Analytics goals. If you need tracking only page views, link clicks and scroll depth, you can do it without GTM.

1. How to [add analytics.js to your site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs#the_google_analytics_tag) or add alternative [async tag](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs#alternative_async_tag)
2. How to set up [Universal Analytics events](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106716)
3. How to [capture outbound links](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920)

Comment: Does this remove the "unused Javascript" warning?  In my case, I want to use GTM if possible because I sometimes need to deliver other scripts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry about. Maybe it's because the GTM plugin has created separate files for these scripts (namely *analytics.js & gtm.js)*.

The analytics script is for "*user tracking purpose*" only and doesn't affect any element of your webpage in any manner.

And because these scripts have nothing to do with that webpage (except of tracking) but still, they're linked to it, the page speed bot may have seen this as unnecessary. Hence, it has marked them as **unused JavaScript**.

Putting these scripts in the source code of your website may get this issue resolved.

**For reference:**
I too have analytics code installed on my website. But, I haven't got any recommendations like this because these scripts are embedded in the source code of my website.

Comment: Embedding the scripts in the source code of the website prevents the scripts from being cached among the pages, so this will result in reduced performance if the user visits multiple pages (because the user will have to download the embedded script for every single page).